# TFS Java SDK slow on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tfs, sdk

I am using the TFS Java SDK (version 11.0) to create some wrapper functions for a website.  I have code that queries Work Items to retrieve information about defects.  When I run the code in Eclipse it takes about 8-10 seconds to retrieve all 1000 Work Items.  That same code when it is run in a web container (Tomcat) takes twice as long.  I cannot figure out why it runs slower in Tomcat vs just running it in Eclipse. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With this data I can not figure out a reason, but you can try to use javOSize, particularly http://www.javosize.com/gettingStarted/slow.html, their tool is free and they are very collaborative to help you find your slow down problems.

You can follow a similar procedure, according to your data I would execute:

Lets imagine your wrapper function is called `com.acme.WrapperClass`, then do:

```
cd REPOSITORY
exec FIND_SLOW_METHODS_EXECUTING_CLASS com.acme.WrapperClass 100 20000
```

This will block for 20s, and will examine any method taking more than 100 ms. As soon as you execute the exec command execute your slow transaction and wait until javOSize returns the output, repeat the same procedure for your eclipse running process.

Paste both output here and hopefully we will find the answer.